# Extract user's Facebook events using iOS native Social framework

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

I want to extract a user's events list (Friend's birthdays, meetings, weddings, etc... ) using the iOS native social framework (or other if exists).

Presently I can only access user's profile and extract his personal infos.